# RecyclerView Adapter- Cannot figure out how to set image resource in typedarray

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am creating a RecyclerView which shows imageview and textview. But Imageview is giving me error when i am setting data in adapter class then it is giving error below:

Imageview cannot be applied to TypedArray

I tried Integer data type also but it is also giving error. Please help to get out of this.

Recycler Adapter Code is here:

```
public class RecyclerAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdpater.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<NewModel>newModels;
Context context;
private int limit = 4;
RecyclerInterface recyclerInterface;
public RecyclerAdpater(ArrayList<NewModel>newModels, Context context){
    this.newModels = newModels;
    this.context = context;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recy_layout, parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(newModels.get(position).getSociallogo()); //here i am getting error.
    holder.textView.setText(newModels.get(position).getSocailtext());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    if(newModels.size() > limit){
        return limit;
    }else {
        return newModels.size();
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView, viewtext;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sociallogo);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.socialtext);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebviewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("URL NAME", newModels.get(getAdapterPosition()).getHref());
            context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Fragment code when i am setting the adapter:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_for_you, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);


    TypedArray logimages = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.social_image);


    String[] logotext = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.social_name);
    String [] href = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.social_url);



    newModels = new ArrayList<>();


    for(int i =0; i<logimages.length();i++) {
        NewModel newModel = new NewModel(logimages, logotext[i], href[i]);
        newModels.add(newModel);
    }



    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

    readapter= new RecyclerAdpater(newModels,getContext());


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(readapter);

    return view;
}
```

NewMode.class file:

```
public class NewModel {
TypedArray sociallogo;
String socailtext;
String href;
public NewModel(TypedArray sociallogo, String socailtext, String href){
    this.sociallogo = sociallogo;
    this.socailtext= socailtext;
    this.href = href;

}
public TypedArray getSociallogo(){
    return sociallogo;
}
public String getSocailtext(){
    return socailtext;
}
public String getHref(){
    return href;
}
```

}

Comment: You don't want a `TypedArray` field in your `NewModel` class. That should be a `Drawable` instead, and you would pass `logimages.getDrawable(i)` in the `NewModel` constructor call in your loop. Don't forget to change the return type on `getSociallogo()` to `Drawable`, too.

Comment: okay thank you so much. Working fine

Comment: Ah, cool. Yeah, I missed that one, but it sounds like you found the `setImageDrawable()` method. However, that made me realize that it is probably better to make `sociallogo` an `int`, and use the resource ID, instead. That way, should you ever add more items to the list, only the items that appear on-screen have their `Drawable`s loaded. If an item is never scrolled on-screen, it's `Drawable` isn't loaded unnecessarily. If you want to do that, simply change the `Drawable` types to `int`, go back to using `setImageResource()`, and use `logimages.getResourceId(i)` instead. Just FYI.

Comment: yeah i found setImageDrawable() and i understand about getResourceID() method. I will use it.